# Removing duplicate values base on a dat and a second column keeping the min value

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I'm trying to remove duplicate values base on the initial date and the policy number, keeping the first entry on a date.
for example if I have two records like:

```
 policy_number        initial_date
    123456                  01/02/97
    123456                  01/02/99
```

and the output I want should be look like this.

```
 policy_number        initial_date
    123456                  01/02/97
```

till' now I've tried this:

```
df.drop_duplicates(['POLICY_NUMBER','initial_date'], keep="first", inplace=True)

 df.sort_values('initial_date').drop_duplicates('initial_date',keep='first')
```

but still not worthit, the output looks same as the original or drop only base on the date ignoring the policy number

fyi both variables are object dtype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df.sort_values('initial_date').drop_duplicates('policy_number',keep='first')
```

or

```
df.sort_values('initial_date').groupby('policy_number',as_index=False).first()
```

**Output**

```
   policy_number initial_date
0         123456     01/02/97
```